# Haskell record syntax desugared

Tags: haskell

I understand how to use record syntax in Haskell, but I have trouble to understand what the thing inside the curly braces *is*.

```
data PairRecord = PR {foo::Int, bar::String} deriving (Eq,Show)
x = (PR {foo=1, bar="init"})
y= x {foo=23}
```

- What *is* this `{foo=23}` thing? The last line looks as if it was an
  argument to the function x, which is clearly not the case.
- Is there
  anything else I can do with `{foo=23}` except placing it right behind
  a record?
- Is there a formal way to desugar it like what we can do with `do` notation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This syntax is called "record update" or "update using field labels" and described in [Section 3.15.3 of the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-540003.15.3). It can be desugared. The exact rules are given in the report. In your example, the desugaring of `x {foo = 23}` is

```
case x of
  PR f b -> PR 23 b
  _      -> error "Update error"
```

Note that the report uses an auxiliary function called "pick" in the desugaring that's described in the [section before, 3.15.2, on "Construction using field labels"](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-520003.15.2).

Comment: So you can desugar x {foo=23}, but {foo=23} alone has no significance and the only usage is in conjunction with an x (or another record) in fron of it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The syntax `{foo = ...}` can only be used in the construction, the pattern match, or the update of a record, and only in combination with other components. It has no meaning in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the types:

```
:t PR
PR :: Int -> String -> PairRecord
```

so it means you need an Int and a String in order to construct a PairRecord.

Now, in the definition of the PairRecord, you've defined accessor:

```
:t foo
foo :: PairRecord -> Int
```

in order to use foo (as accessor), you needs to supply a PairRecord. You gets an
Int as return value:

```
foo y
23
```

It means as well foo alone has no meaning, this function needs a PairRecord.

As kosmikus already point out, the syntax

```
y= x {foo=23}
```

creates y from an existing PairRecord with an integer set to 23 (with the help of the accessor function).

Comment: foo *does* have a well defined meaning: it is a function from PairRecord to Int. However, {foo=23} is nothing at all without an x in front if it.

Answer (score -2):

What you need is called [lenses](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial). But firstly you must install package lens.

Comment: Oh god, are lenses becoming Haskell's jQuery?

Comment: As much as I like lenses, this really doesn't address what's being asked. It might make a good side note, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @David Young: this isn't a side note, this is a "guide". I wanted to spare him from the desugaring cycles.

Comment: @Steven Dobay: I personally believe it is best to learn the foundational concepts first and then you can learn the tricks and better techniques by building on those concepts. This seems like someone asking how to do addition and telling them to just use a calculator (in this case, a very elaborate and potentially intimidating calculator).

Comment: @David Young: You're right! And someone before me showed him the basics(desugaring) and after that i offered him the lenses. This is his choice what he want to use. But firstly,- as you said - it is recommended to get practice in basics.

Comment: @StevenDobay: Actually, that's a good point. Sorry, I wasn't thinking about that.